# get_forward_data() deprecated warning in pandas v0.12

Tags: python, pandas

This is a very useful function to acquire options chains for an underlying from Yahoo. I see in the source for version 0.12 and 0.13 it will be deprecated. I'm curious if there will be replacement functionality?

Also, it seems to break if the `months` argument is greater than 2. Any thoughts on this?

Please see [`Options.get_forward_data()`](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/blob/master/pandas/io/data.py#L800) on GitHub for the source.

Comment: Did you checkout out this issues related to this? https://github.com/pydata/pandas/search?q=get_forward_data&ref=cmdform&type=Issues

Take a look at the PR the introduced the deprecation.

Comment: Ahhh...https://github.com/dstephens99/pandas/blob/9b859cd4389f4af497e85e4860429989b7f47f6e/pandas/io/data.py

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [github](https://github.com/dstephens99/pandas/blob/9b859cd4389f4af497e85e4860429989b7f47f6e/pandas/io/data.py) code where a new function was pushed.